# Android - How can I display six buttons using this structure?

Tags: android

I would like to display six buttons in XML using the following structure:

[image]

I already tried to do it but it doesn't work for all screen sizes. I would like to draw a structure that works in all screen sizes, can you guys help me?

Comment: You could achieve this crudely using weighted layouts within multiple LinearLayouts. However, there are third party libs that perform this function - I suggest researching them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered your query using Linear Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:weightSum="10"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ActivityState">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <Button android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <Button android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <Button android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps ! :)